# Scaling mixed models for PCA using dudi.mix

Tags: r, pca, categorical-data

I am trying to do a kselect model from the `adehabitatHS` which uses commands from `ade4` package.  I am trying to determine if I need to scale my variables.   My surface understanding is that the k-select is basically a fancy PCA.  In their example they scaled their variables, but their variables were only continuous measures.  I have mixed categorical and continuous variables.   In their example, they scale their variables before they use the command `dudi.pca` which from my understanding this is needed to set up the k-select.  I know from reading the dudi help in the `ade4` vinette that I should use `dudi.mix` here instead of `.pca`, but what to do about scaling?  Do I need to scale my variables? Do I need to scale all variables? Do I need to scale all the variables EXCEPT the categorical variable?   I can't find reading material that explains what is happening in the dudi/pca mixed process in sufficient detail.

Below is the example code from the k-select help if you would like to see what I am referring to.

```
data(puechabonsp)
locs <- puechabonsp$relocs
    map <- puechabonsp$map
pc <- mcp(locs[,"Name"])
hr <- hr.rast(pc, map)
cp <- count.points(locs[,"Name"], map)

## prepares the data for the kselect analysis
x <- prepksel(map, hr, cp)
tab <- x$tab

## Example of analysis with two variables: the slope and the elevation.
tab <- tab[,((names(tab) == "Slope")|(names(tab) == "Elevation"))]
tab <- scale(tab)

## A K-select analysis
acp <- dudi.pca(tab, scannf = FALSE, nf = 2)
kn <- kselect(acp, x$factor, x$weight, scannf = FALSE, nf = 2)
```

Again, their example only used continuous variables.  Does the dudi.mix scale the variables appropriately in the code that we don't see?

Comment: I think that dudi.mix() would do the right thing in case you have continuous and categorical variables, but you might want to post your question to [the ADEList](http://listes.univ-lyon1.fr/wws/info/adelist) to get a more rapid response from the ADE developers themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this as a partial explanation in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatHS/vignettes/adehabitatHS.pdf.

> The function dudi.pca is to be used when all the variables present in
>   the data.frame are numeric. The function dudi.acm is to be used when
>   all the vari- ables present in the data.frame are factors. The
>   function dudi.hillsmith (or, equivalently, dudi.mix) is to be used
>   when the data.frame contains both types of variables. These functions,
>   used as a preliminary to the GNESFA, are needed to scale the table
>   suitably (so that all the variables have the same mean and the same
>   variance), and to compute the weights of the variables in the
>   analysis. For example, the use of dudi.hillsmith on a table containing
>   a numeric variable and a factor with four levels ensures that the
>   factor will have the same weight in the analysis as the numeric
>   variable

I can only assume the dudi.hillsmith is scaling the data correctly and I do not need to scale my data before using the k-select.